# Fetch triggers on previous screen when value on next screen changes

Tags: reactjs, native

My react native project has screen A which is the main menu and screen B which is the edit profile screen. If I navigate to B and change the text there (which contains my full name), it should update and display my full name on screen A. Currently I have a fetch function which displays the previous name that is pulled from the API. Screen B updates the API, but navigating back to screen A doesn't show the new updated full name.

I was thinking of passing the new stored value to the previous screen using goBack but that doesn't work. I wanted to store the value, then call it in screen A simultaneously with the other API call.

That doesn't work. If anyone has any code or suggestions to constantly update the home screen by triggering the fetch API (unless there's a better way to do it), please let me know.

```
.then((response) => response.json())  
    .then ((res) => {

    console.log(res); 

        if(res.errornum == 200) {
            //AsyncStorage.setItem('email', res.email);
            this.props.navigation.goBack( {savedUser: this.state.savedUsername});   
            this.props.navigation.goBack();
            alert("User details have been updated!")        
        }
        else if (res.errornum != 200){
            //alert(res.message);
            alert("Couldn't save details. Try again.")
            } 
        })
        .done();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to trigger Fetch API to get the updated value.
From the question you phrased, the screen A(Main menu) is your parent screen and screen B(Edit profile) is the child.
You have to pass 2 props from parent to child one the variable 'name' and two the call back function to change that name.

Here's a quick example

```
Class Mainmenu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name = 'John'
        };
    }


    changeName = (value) => {
        this.setState({
            name: value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <EditProfile 
          name={this.state.name}
          changeName={this.changeName}
          />);
    }
}
```

In the Edit Profile  use the changeName function.

Comment: Is this code written in Screen A or Screen B? Or is it in a separate class (with Screen B exported and called as a JSX)

Comment: This should be written on your screen A.

Comment: I keep getting an error. Here is what I am calling on Screen B for the name function:     `<TextInput style={{fontFamily: 'Avenir Next', fontWeight: '700', fontSize: 18, color: 'black'}} value={this.state.User} maxLength={28} onChangeText={this.newUsername}/>`

Comment: <TextInput style={{fontFamily: 'Avenir Next', fontWeight: '700', fontSize: 18, color: 'black'}} value={this.state.User} maxLength={28} onChangeText={this.props.newUsername}/>

The newUsername function should be accessed via props as below
onChangeText={this.props.newUsername}

Answer (score 0):

Is the fetch being called from the componentDidMount lifecycle hook ?
If so, then add a condition there to not make a call if the name is already there in the state that you are using.